# WKWebview Password API Autofill

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

I am attempting to use Password Autofill API as seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element?language=objc)

*important. HTML is being served by localhost

I am using WKWebview and a local html file served up in a local web server. I have deployed the Apple-app-site-association file and to test this Ive create a native text field view with a username and password and this worked great. The app autofilled the correct credentials.

When attempting this inside of the html code the username keyboard did not even show the key lock not did it make suggestions. The password field did show the key lock and I opened manually and chose my password and the fields filled in appropriately.

So my problem is iOS is not auto suggesting my login credentials which defeats the purpose of implementing this.

Here is my snippet from my html

```
<input id="user-text-field" type="email" autocomplete = "username" tv-auto-focus class="text-single tvFocusItem tvAutoFocus" ng-model="username" required="true"  placeholder="{{::('FORMS.DEFAULT.EMAIL' | spTranslate)}}" ng-disabled="!registerEnabled() || askingForPassword && username"/>

<input id="password-text-field" type="password" autocomplete = "current-password" tv-auto-focus class="text-single tvFocusItem tvAutoFocus" pattern=".{1,}" required ng-model="$parent.password"  required="true" placeholder="{{::('FORMS.DEFAULT.PASS' | spTranslate)}}" ng-disabled="!$parent.registerEnabled()"/>
```

So any help would be appreciated.

**Updated. The username shows the lock key when all fields are enabled. The autofill/suggest still does not work

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: Nope. I wrote to Apple who said it's a bug but doesn't seem like they've addressed it. @RamGrg